# How to compile file .cpp to exe with comperssion natively?

Tags: c++, filesize, lzma

In question: How to compile file .cpp to exe, but with comperssion natively?

Comment: `g++ -o foo foo.cpp && tar -xzvf foo.tar.gz foo.exe`?

Comment: Compression, not compersion. Also: You don't compile it that way, you compile it normally and use a tool to compress the exe afterwards. Google it yourself as I never needed something like that myself.

Comment: _compersion_ for space/portability ? Why don't you directly write in assembly or brainfck :P Why is this even tag for `C++`. It has nothing to do with any programming language. Just get the executable binary, use tool to compress the executable

Comment: @P0W (frustrating, isn't it? especially the lack of effort and the tag abuse.)

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." Anyway, [this is what compersion means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compersion), and it has nothing to do with compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just compile it using your normal C++ compiler. Then compress the resulting .exe file using [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net).